# Performing a function on column values based on index locations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with 3 columns; `['close', 'BUY', 'SELL']`. The `'BUY'` and `'SELL'` columns are booleans and indicate index positions where to buy and sell - they are spread out through many rows - around 3000. I have been able to find the indexes where these booleans are true (1) using:

```
returns[returns.BUY == 1]
```

I would like to be able to find the nth index point based off these boolean locations and then apply a function to the 'close' column values that correspond with the index points, n and n+n.

Thanks!

[image: Need a function that would only apply if the conditionals in column 'BUY' are true (1)]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index with

```
returns[returns.BUY == 1].index.values.astype(int)
```

Edit:
Not sure if I understand you correctly. You could try constructing the index of +n with

```
for i in range(1, len(df) - n):
    df.loc[i, 'index+n'] = df.loc[i+n, 'index']
```

And then you can use an apply function to use whatever conditions you would like to use.

Comment: Yes, I have found the index already. I am wondering how to apply a function to the column named 'close' based off those specific index points, and then the index points of +n - both then referring back to the corresponding values in the 'close' column.

Comment: Do you know a function that would allow me to only apply it to instances where a conditional is true in a certain column? I have added a picture of the dataframe to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I would probably try `np.where()`

Answer (score 0):

You almost got there, just add column name to your slice and apply `your_function`

```
returns.loc[returns.BUY == 1, 'close'].apply(your_function)
```

Comment: Do you know a function that would allow me to only apply it to instances where a conditional is true in a certain column? I have added a picture of the dataframe to illustrate what I mean.